# Measuring distance between discharge point, along river, until next intersection with another river?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arc-hydro, rivers

i hope someone can answer me my simple question. I have two sets of data

1. a river network --> line feature
2. discharge points along those rivers --> Point Data

The discharge points represent wastewater treatment plants. I try to find those treatment plants which don't have a inflow of another river, for a minimum of 2 km downstream. This means the river from this point on does not intersect with another river for at least 2km.

How can i find those plants? Are there any tools for this? What about the Arc Hydro tools?

Comment: have a look at linear referencing tools in ArcGIS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the distance of a point along a polyline?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6476/how-to-find-the-distance-of-a-point-along-a-polyline)

Comment: This question can be solved in different ways; it does not appear to be an exact duplicate of others. For example, it could be solved by creating a layer consisting of all portions of the river system lying 2 Km *upstream* of any confluence, and then using spatial selection to find all discharge points not adjacent to that layer. This layer could be created in various ways, some of which are discussed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87649. -- But this is not the only possible solution.